# Установка видео в качестве фона блока

Tags: html, css

Не растягивается на всю ширину экрана.

```css
#vidos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

video {
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="vidos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> <video autoplay loop muted> <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> </video> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="vidos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> <video autoplay loop muted> <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> </video> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html code: `<div class="container-fluid" id="vidos">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
         <video  autoplay loop muted>
         <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
         </video>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div> <div class="container-fluid" id="vidos">
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      <video  autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
   </video>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>`

Comment: css code:`#vidos{
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; 
}
video {
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}`

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

А чуть больше кода привести ты не смог? Из этого отрывка ничего не понятно, ни какая структура страницы, ни то есть ли родительские элементы блока `<div class="container-fluid" id="vidos">`, ни то какие их стили установлен.

Ну в крайнем случаи можешь поставить css `position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;` для блока с `id="vidos"`, это установит его позиционирование независимо от других блоков, но опять таки не могу сказать точно решит ли это твою проблему.